# How do you completely redirect the URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, backend, window.open

Instead of using the window.open command in javascript -- which only creates a pop-up window -- how would someone use javascript to reassign the URL to a completely new area?

Comment: Better yet, how would you open a new tab in the browser.

Comment: Javascript can't distinguish between tabs and windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "new URL";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //Will take you to Google.
See this write up  http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location

Answer (score 0):

or if you don't want the current page in the browser history, use

```
window.location.replace("New URL");
```